# Realm Migration: Update multiple objects and fallback strategy?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I do not understand how to migrate multiple objects. For example how do I introduce a string "identifier" on object Settings and Person?

```
func configureRealm(){

        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
            schemaVersion: 1,
            migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

                migration.enumerate(Settings.className()) { oldObject, newObject in

                    if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
                        newObject!["identifier"] = NSUUID().UUIDString
                    }
                }
        })
    }
```

And is it possible to introduce a general fallback strategy: When migration fails the model should reset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the migration block you can just add a call to `Migration().enumerate(_:_:)` for the `Person` object:

```
func configureRealm(){

        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
            schemaVersion: 1,
            migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

                migration.enumerate(Settings.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                    if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
                        newObject!["identifier"] = NSUUID().UUIDString
                    }
                }
                migration.enumerate(Person.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                    if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
                        // change whatever needs to be changed
                    }
                }
        })
    }
```

Or you could just delete the realm file when `let realm = try Realm()` throws an error:

```
do {
   let realm = try Realm()
   ...
} catch {
   let path = RLMRealmConfiguration.defaultRealmPath()
   try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(path)
}
```

Comment: thx - I tried it with a comma between the blocks - to complicated. Perhaps you can add this to your documentation?

Comment: What exactly should I add?

Comment: how to update two objects. This is why I was asking.

Comment: But that's already in my answer. It updates all the `Settings` objects and all the `Persons` objects. You need to enumerate each object seperately

Comment: Sorry - I thought your were from Realm. The official documentation should contain such an example. Your answer is perfect

Comment: Ah, now I understand ;-)

Comment: For development, I'd recommend to prefer the latter strategy. So you'll need to keep only those code paths in the migration block and create versions for schema manifestations which are released and affect realms existing in the wild. Beside the short examples in our official documentation, there is [a further example app related to Migrations in our repo.](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift-2.1/Migration/AppDelegate.swift#L69-L103)